# C++ constructor call default constructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a problem calling the default constructor from other in c++. In Java was something like this:

```
class Book {
  static private int i;
  private String s;

  public Book() {
    i++;
  }

  public Book(String s) {
    this();
    this.s = s;
  }
}
```

Comment: In C++11 you can use delegating constructors

Comment: That code isn't valid C++ ( I think you already know that ).  What's the question?

Comment: This is a java code i need to know how will be this code in c++

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454823/invoke-another-constructor-in-the-same-class/

Comment: Time to read a good book on C++.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: That's java code, not c++ code, people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a compiler capable of delegating constructor, just call the default constructor in the initializer list:

```
class Book
{
public:
    Book()
    { ... }

    Book(const std::string& s)
    : Book()
    { ... }
};
```

Else you can make a function for common initialization and call it from all constructors:

```
class Book
{
public:
    Book()
    { construct(); }

    Book(const std::string& s)
    {
        construct();
        // Other stuff
    }

private:
    void construct()
    { ... }
};
```

Comment: Strange in c# it Works fine, but in c++ not... well i will create a function that will hold the code i need.

Answer (score 9):

In C++ we have *delegating constructors*. There are two things to know about it:

- They are available only since C++11, and not all compilers already implement them.
- The correct syntax is to use the constructor's initializer list:

  `Book(std::string s) : Book() { ... }`